# Adding authentication throws an error on successful login (Using Agile Toolkit)

Tags: php, user-interface, frameworks, atk4

I tried to add $this->api->auth->check(); to my test.php page and it throws an error when I correctly type in the login credentials:

```
Error in AJAX response: SyntaxError: invalid XML attribute value
Exception_Logic

Method is not defined for this object

Additional information:

    class: Model
    method: tryLoadBy
    arguments: Array ( [0] => email [1] => demo )
```

It has the same problem with the included "DVD rental" example and when I try to login to the admin section it gives an error.

Comment: The error message on it's own is not really enough information to help you yet. Can you post the whole of your test.php page and also any changes you've made to Frontend.php.

Answer (score 1):

I think it may be related to this bug:
https://github.com/atk4/atk4/issues/67